# Eliminar TODOS los nodos de un árbol binario de búsqueda en Java

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, árboles-binarios

Necesito un método que elimine todos los nodos que están dentro de un árbol binario. No me interesa eliminar un nodo en específico, necesito eliminar todos.
Aquí es donde agrego un nuevo nodo:

```
public class NodoBinario {
public int dato;
public String nombre;
public NodoBinario Hizq, Hder;
Familiar f= new Familiar();

// Constructores
public NodoBinario(Familiar f) {
    dato = f.getEdad();
    nombre = f.getNombre();
    NodoBinario Hizq, Hder = null;
}

// Inserción de un elemento
public void InsertaBinario(Familiar f) {

    int edad = f.getEdad();
    if(edad < dato) {
        if (Hizq == null)
            Hizq = new NodoBinario(f);
        else
            Hizq.InsertaBinario(f);
    } else {
        if (edad > dato) {
            if (Hder == null)
                Hder = new NodoBinario(f);
            else
                Hder.InsertaBinario(f);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Cualquier aporte sería de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En java no hace falta *recorrer* el árbol para eliminar sus nodos. Puedes eliminar la referencia al nodo raíz y esto provocará que el *recolector de basura* se encargue de eliminar todos los nodos (suponiendo que se cumple la regla de que no hay referencias externas a ningún nodo).

Si por alguna razón quieres hacerlo de manera manual, habría que recorrer los nodos e ir *eliminando* las referencias. En este caso, lo natural es hacerlo de manera recursiva, digamos que tenemos un método dentro de la clase `NodoBinario` para *eliminar* los nodos *en orden*, cuyo cometido sería el de, recursivamente, eliminar las referencias al nodo, de manera que el recolector de basura eventualmente lo libere, algo como:

```
public void Eliminar() {
    if (Hizq != null) {
      Hizq.Eliminar();
      Hizq = null;
    }
    if (Hder != null) {
      Hder.Eliminar();
      Hder = null;
    }
}
```

Luego, para eliminar todo el árbol, invocas a este método sobre el nodo raíz, al que eventualmente también liberas, algo como:

```
  NodoBinario raiz;
  // creas y trabajas con el árbol....
  // y luego:
  raiz.Eliminar(); 
  raiz = null;
```

La asignación a `null` sería necesaria solo si la variable sigue existiendo y se utiliza después de ese punto.

Sobre tu código, me llama la atención que declaras variables cuyo nombre inicia en letra mayúscula. Nada lo impide, pero he observado que en java existe la convención de nombrar las clases e interfaces con inicial mayúscula, y las variables con inicial minúscula.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, me expresé de manera incorrecta.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! resolviste mi duda.